# Define and test a function myRange

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/sandbox7723bf31/nt-test-68764d5e.py", line 2, in
from testmyrange import myRange
ImportError: cannot import name 'myRange' from 'testmyrange' (/root/sandbox7723bf31/testmyrange.py)

```
#define and test a function range with a main defined
#define myRange() method

def myRange(p, q == None and r == None):
  
    if p == 0 and q == None and r == None:
         return []
    if r == None:
         step = 1
    else:
         step = r

    if q == None:
        start = 0
        stop = p
    else:
        start = p
      stop = q

    res = []
    i = start

def main():

    while True:
        res.append(i)

    if step > 0 and i + step >= stop:
        break
    elif step < 0 and i + step <= stop:
        break
    else:
        i = i + step
    return res

#call main and end program

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    
    main()
```

Comment: 1) Incorrect syntax `def myRange(p, q == None and r == None):`.  Should be: `def myRange(p, q = None, r = None):`  2) Incorrect Indent:  `while True:
        res.append(i)` (i.e. currently an infinite loop) and break is outside loop. 3) In main none of the variables are defined before using.

Comment: Purpose of main?  Meaning what is it trying to do?

Comment: Teacher said we have to design a main that calls the my range program. Also i changed == to = in def myRange and am still getting a invalid syntax error.

Comment: @Heather--coded a myRange and added some simple test in main.  Let me know if it's not clear.  Made the code verbose to make it easier to follow.  Normal Python implementation would be much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

**Code with Simple Tests of MyRange**

```
def myRange(p = None, q = None, r = None):
  " Provides version of range function "

  # Get arguments which are not none
  args = []
  for i in [p, q, r]:
    if i is not None:
        args.append(i)
   
  # Find start, stop, step from args
  if len(args) == 1:
    # Only one non-none
    start = 0
    stop = args[0]
    step = 1
  elif len(args) == 2:
    start, stop, step = *args, 1 # unpack two from args and add 1 value for step
  elif len(args) == 3:
    start, stop, step = args    # assign all arguments
  
  # Generate list of values based upon
  # start, stop, step
  res = []
  if step > 0:
    # list is incrementing up
    while start < stop:
      res.append(start)
      start += step
  else:
    # list is incrementing down
    while start > stop:
      res.append(start)
      start += step

  return res

def check_result(actual, expected):
    " Checks if results is as expected "
    print("Test: Expected {}, Actual {}, Equal? {}".format(expected, actual, actual == expected))

def main():
  check_result(myRange(0), [])
  check_result(myRange(10), list(range(10)))
  check_result(myRange(0, 5, 2), list(range(0, 5, 2)))
  check_result(myRange(10, 0, -2), list(range(10, 0, -2)))
  check_result(myRange(10, 0, 2), [])
  
if __name__ == "__main__" :
  main()
```

**Output**

```
Test: Expected [], Actual [], Equal? True
Test: Expected [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Actual [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Equal? True
Test: Expected [0, 2, 4], Actual [0, 2, 4], Equal? True
Test: Expected [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], Actual [10, 8, 6, 4, 2], Equal? True
Test: Expected [], Actual [], Equal? True
```

Comment: Here is the new error i am getting on stop value test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/sandbox8d5f7b5b/nt-test-03d7c29c.py", line 5, in test_unit_test
    self.assertEqual(myRange(10),  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [] != [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Second list contains 10 additional elements.
First extra element 0:
0
- []
+ [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
FAILED (failures=1)
Test Contents
class UnitTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_unit_test(self):
        self.assertEqual(myRange(10),  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

Comment: @Heather--morning heather.  Try the "new improved code".

Comment: good morning, again thanks for your help.  I am getting the same error code. except it says assertion error

Comment: not sure we have learned about assertion yet do you know where i would find more info on this module?

Comment: @Heather--no problem. Since your previous comment showed the result of a unit test I thought perhaps you knew about asserts.  Anyway, changed main to call a check_result function that reports if the actual and expected results are the same.  Function main then calls check_result several times to see if result is as expected.  I was sure which version of print you're familiar with so I just used one of the simplest which prints a string accord to format.  If you haven't covered this let me know and we can simplify this further.